# R: Shiny - observeEvent invalidates too often

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am building a shiny web app, and am running into an issue when using the observeEvent function. I use it to observe changes to a few UI elements, which are then used as arguments to a function that uses `renderPlot`.

The problem is, when one of the UI elements is changed, it calls the function twice. Once with the original value before the alteration, and again with the new value. This is causing problems that I won't describe in detail, but I want to modify whatever is necessary so that it only calls the function once, with the new value. Does anybody know why `observeEvent` behaves like this or how I might get around it? Thanks

Edit: Here is the suspect code

from server:

```
    observeEvent(c(input$single_expNum, input$trait_exp, 
       input$plotExp_by, input$single_expDayRange), {
          output$single_expGraph <- plotExperiment(dataset, 
            input$single_expNum, input$trait_exp, 
            input$plotExp_by, input$single_expDayRange)
       }
    )
```

Comment: `observeEvent` treats everything in the `handlerExpr` as if they were wrapped in an `isolate` function, so it should only be triggered when an `input` or `reactiveValue` in the `eventExpr` is invalidated (changed). Without looking at your code, it's hard to determine what's going wrong. Could you post a [MCVE] of your problem?

Comment: I've updated the post to contain a piece of the code

Comment: You should have curly brackets if you are passing more than one input to be observed.  `observeEvent({input$single_expNum, input$trait_exp..},{...} )`

Comment: Why are you using `observeEvent` here? Since every reactive element in `handlerExpr` is also in `eventExpr` this works exactly the same as using `reactive`

Comment: That only works syntactically if I keep it as a collection inside of the recommended curly brackets, and even then it didn't have any effect on the problem...

Comment: @divibisan No real reason, if this would be more efficient to accomplish with reactive() I would like to do that, I am having trouble figuring out exactly what that would look like though

Answer (score 1):

It's hard for me to say exactly why this is happening, but shiny often does wonky things when your expressions are over-complicated or designed in a way that is different than the designers of shiny intended. This is how I would rewrite your code example to make it more in line with shiny doctrine. I wouldn't be surprised if that fixed your problem:

```
output$single_expGraph <- renderPlot({
    # I assume here that plotExperiment() is a function that returns a plot
    plotExperiment(dataset,
                   input$single_expNum, input$trait_exp,
                   input$plotExp_by, input$single_expDayRange)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, I agree with @divibisan that the direct use of `renderPlot` should work nicely. In addition, I think it's safe to say that `renderPlot` is the pattern recommended by Shiny. If your reactive expression (whichever you may ultimately choose) gives you trouble because of frequent updates you can slow it down with [`debounce` or `throttle`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.4/debounce.html).

Debouncing means that invalidation is held off for `millis` milliseconds. The reactive expression will only be validated until that time window has passed without a subsequent invalidation which may have an effect like this: ooo-oo-oo---- => -----------o-

Throttling, on the other hand, will not reset the time window with each invalidation. A throttled reactive "will invalidate regularly, at a rate equal to or slower than than the time window" (from the manual): ooo-oo-oo---- => o--o--o--o---